# How do I detect when my window is minimized with wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, minimize

I am writing a small wxPython utility.

I would like to use some event to detect when a user minimizes the application/window.

I have looked around but did not find an event like wx.EVT_MINIMIZE that I could bind to.

Anyone know of a way that can be used to detect this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a handler for the [wx.EVT_ICONIZE](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.IconizeEvent-class.html) event.